# How to extract subcollections from documentsnapshots of firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a project on flutter where I am getting snapshots of documents by

```
final snapshot = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('revisableFlashcards').snapshots(),
```

[image: My database model is shown here]

I want to know how I can extract my subcollections from the snapshot and get documents in subcollection from the firstsnapshot.

[image: my subcollection is shown here]

I have tried some way by which I am getting collection

```
CollectionReference subjects=db.collection('revisableFlashcards').doc('MBBS')
   .collection('First');
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await subjects.get();
```

Comment: What is `col` in your second code snippet, and how is that variable initialized? Don't show that in a comment though, but please edit your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: Have you checked this [article](https://medium.com/@yasassandeepa007/how-to-get-sub-collection-data-from-firebase-with-flutter-fe1bda8456ca)?

Comment: I have edited the code col can be the name of any subcollection.

Comment: Can you try [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67520543/18265570)?