# Firestore reads specific collection data

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore

This is my firestore, I want to read all the data in the "RechargeCoin" collection, I tried many ways but can't, who can help me
--> Users/uid/RechargeCoin/postid
[image: This is my firestore]

I want to get all the contents of "UID" and "PostID", how should I do it?
Here is my code

```
 let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("Users").document().collection("RechargeCoin")
            .order(by: "date", descending: true)
        
            .addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
```

I want to update the value in postID, but use: collectionGroup("RechargeCoin"), but the document cannot be updated, it shows: collectionGroup("RechargeCoin"), what should I do?

```
fireStoreDB.collectionGroup("RechargeCoin")
.document("\(String(describing: self.postArray[indexPath.row].postId))")
.updateData (userInfo as [String : Any], completion: {(error) in
            
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from your query you are not particular about any document in `users` collection and want only documents within `RechargeCoin` subcollection sounds like perfect job for [Collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) using `db.collectionGroup("RechargeCoin")` as follows:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
  .db.collectionGroup("RechargeCoin")
  .order(by: "date", descending: true)
  .getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
    if let err = err {
      print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
      for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
        print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
      }
    }
  }
```

Reference from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67520543/20239914)

Comment: thank you for your help!!
I want to ask again: I want to update the value in postID, but I can’t update the document when I use: collectionGroup("RechargeCoin"), it shows: collectionGroup("RechargeCoin"), what should I do?
I edited the question